# SQL Simple Equation (2 columns as something)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I'm new to Linq and am having difficulties converting part of an SQL Query to Linq...

The part in my query is there I Subtract one column from the other and set it as a new column name... How do you do this in Linq?

The part of the SQL is as follows: -

'[ColumnA] - [ColumnB] As Actual'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your LINQ query you can [project the result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387028.aspx) of the query to an existing class (not the one generated by Entity framework or LINQ to SQL) or [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) like:

```
var query = from t in yourList
            select new 
             {
               Actual = t.ColumnA - t.ColumnB
             };
```